# Join the original sorted files, include 2 fields in one file and 1 field in 2nd file

Tags: linux

I need help with linux command.
I have 2 files StockSort and SalesSort. They are sorted and they have 3 fields each. I know how to sort 1 field in 1st file and 1 field in 2nd file. But I can't get a right syntax for joining two fields in 1st file and only 1 field in second file. I also need to save it i na new file.
So far I have this command, but it doesn't work.I think the mistake is in "2,3" part, where I need to combine two fields from the 1st file.

```
join -1 2,3 -2 2 StockSort SalesSort >FinalReport

StockSort file
3976:diode:350
4105:resistor:750
4250:resistor:500

SalesSort file
3976:120:net
4105:250:chg
5500:100:pde

Output should be like this:
3976:350:120
4105:750:250
4250:500:100
```

Comment: Can you update your post with samples of the files and required output?

Comment: @IanKenney updated with tables that need to be joined by the fields

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @IanKenney updated

Comment: How do you get the final line of `4250:500:100` in the output since the final line of SalesSort is `5500:100:pde`? The value of `5500` is not defined in the first file. It should just be two lines of output given those two input files, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
join -t: -o 1.1,1.3,2.2 stocksort salesort
```

where

```
-t set the column separator
-o is the output format (a comma sep. list of filenumber.fieldnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":"} 
       FNR==NR {Stock[$1]=$3; next} 
       $1 in Stock{ print $1,Stock[$1],$2}' StockSort SalesSort
```